# tkinter filedialog.askopenfilename() window won't close in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was playing around with tkinter in python 2x and whenever I use `filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` I can easily open a file for use and the dialog window closes automatically after.

Somehow this doesn't work in python 3x. An example code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

    def character_mentions():
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            dict_of_mentions = {rows[1]:rows[2] for rows in reader}
        print(dict_of_mentions)
```

This gives me the output I'm seeking, but the the empty root window stays open, blank. When I press the X button, it freezes and forces me to shut it down with the task manager.

Any ideas on what to do here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it actually the file dialog that's remaining, or the empty root window that Tkinter gives you whether you want one or not?  If your only intended use of Tkinter is a file or other dialog, it would be best to explicitly create and hide that root window: `tkinter.Tk().withdraw()` perhaps.

Comment: @jasonharper ah, yes - that's the window I meant, thanks. I edited my question. I added that line but it didn't work, sadly.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You are missing a tkinter instance, a mainloop, and a call to the function. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a tkinter instance and then hide the main window.

In the function you can simply `destroy()` the tkinter instance once your function is complete.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_withdraw() # this completely hides the root window
# root.iconify() # this will move the root window to a minimized icon.

def character_mentions():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        dict_of_mentions = {rows[1]:rows[2] for rows in reader}
    print(dict_of_mentions)
    root.destroy()

character_mentions()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a drop-in replacement for `filedialog` that implements the described solution you can use the following class (myfile.py):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class filedialog(tk.Tk):

    @classmethod
    def askopenfilename(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        root = cls()
        root.wm_withdraw()
        files = fd.askopenfilename(*args, **kwargs)
        root.destroy()
        return files
```

This way the usage syntax doesn't need to change e.g. instead of
`from tkinter import filedialog` you can use `from myfile import filedialog` and just use `filedialog.askopenfilename()`